# Using reinterpret_cast with ARC enabled

Tags: c++, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, reinterpret-cast

I have included a header file for a library in my ARC-enabled Objective-C project.

I know the library is not compiled with ARC enabled, but the problem is the header file of the library, specifically these lines:

```
template <typename Type_>
static inline Type_ &MSHookIvar(id self, const char *name) {
    Ivar ivar(class_getInstanceVariable(object_getClass(self), name));
    void *pointer(ivar == NULL ? NULL : reinterpret_cast<char *>(self) + ivar_getOffset(ivar));
    return *reinterpret_cast<Type_ *>(pointer);
}
```

I get this error:

```
Cast of an Objective-C pointer to 'char *' is disallowed with ARC
```

Is it possible to fix this error?

The whole header file can be found here: http://puu.sh/sTrH

Comment: It's impossible to cast objc var types to c var types.

Comment: Try to use `void *self`.

Comment: did you manage to fix it ?

Comment: @Osa rob mayoff's answer worked for me, see https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev/pull/15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the initialization of `pointer` to this:

```
void *pointer(ivar == NULL ? NULL : reinterpret_cast<char *>((__bridge void *)self) + ivar_getOffset(ivar));
```

Comment: Why do non-apple headers always need modification?

Answer (score -1):

Go to the target of your project and select the Build Phases tab.  Open the Compile Sources section and find that header file.  Add the compiler flag "-fno-objc-arc" minus the quotes.  This will cause that file to be compiled regularly and should fix your issue assuming the code works in a non arc environment.